# next.js: router.push does not work on docker image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, next.js, deployment

I am using Router.push() to navigate between pages. This works on local and does not give any errors during build, But on server following error shows up on my page.

Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).

And the following errors show up in browser console.

DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
Error rendering page:  Error: Cancel rendering route

It works with docker compose up on the main folder of the project but not when I'm building and deploying a docker image from gitlab ci.

I have tried setting strict mode to false but it's not working.